# Cuted is always inserting a character "7" between strips

Tags: two-column, cuted

I have a two column document and in it, I have some images I wish to be full screen, so I have used strips. The following is a sample code:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true, allcolors=blue]{hyperref}
\usepackage{cuted}


\title{Your Paper}
\author{You}

\begin{document}
\maketitle


\begin{strip}
  \centering\noindent
  \includegraphics[width=0.8\linewidth]{frog.jpg}
\end{strip}

\begin{strip}
  \centering\noindent
  \includegraphics[width=0.8\linewidth]{frog.jpg}
\end{strip}

\begin{strip}
  \centering\noindent
  \includegraphics[width=0.8\linewidth]{frog.jpg}
\end{strip}
\bibliographystyle{alpha}
\bibliography{sample}

\end{document}
```

This is always adding a character "7" in between strips. Sample of how it's looking:

[image]

Comment: if you use `example-image` not `frog` then people can test your example, that image is available in tex distributions for such tests

Comment: If I use example-image I get `! Undefined control sequence.
\@outputdblcol ...i \@combinedblfloats \@setmarks ` and no output.

Comment: AFAIK this usually happens, if there are several `strip` immediate following each other. It does not happen, if you have only one `strip` per page. For example, add some text (e.g. `\blindtext[3]` using package `blindtext`) before the `strip` and combine all three environments to one. Related: [I am trying to span lengthy equations across a two-column page in Overleaf. When I use the \begin{strip}, a digit is displayed in b/w two equations](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/697359/277964)

Comment: your example works in texlive 2021 but gives an error in texlive 2022 and 2023. after an error please always show the error message, not any pdf you get by scrolling past the error, which is not intended to be usable.